# Can all vector spaces be made into normed spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Can all vector spaces be made into normed spaces (even trivial ones)? Vectorspace could be of infinite dimension.

**Update:** I don't know how to make this question more specific. I am talking about a very general vectorspace. It can be any kind of vectorspace (finite dimensional, infinite dimensional) with any kind of underlying field ($\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ or other). It seems like most sources I have simply start by discussing the definition of a normed vectorspace without discussing when it is possible for a vectorspace to have a norm. So I am thinking maybe there could be a vectorspace that we cannot define a norm on it? I couldn't think of an example myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes (as long as you have an absolute on the field, and you do not use non-common axioms schemes for your set-theory).

Just recall that every vector space has a basis, fix one, and define the norm, e.g., as the $\infty$-norm  of the coordinates in this basis.

Comment: My concern is I'm not sure what would happen if we are talking about Schauder basis?

Comment: @Misakov Basis here means Hamel basis. When people speak of Schauder bases, usually they say it explicitely.

Comment: @Misakov the notion of Schauder basis makes no sense in the context of an abstract vector space.

Comment: For more details about norms in arbitrary fields you can see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2568042/113061

Answer (score 6):

Sure. Take a (Hamel) basis $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ of your vector space $V$ (its existence is guaranteed by Zorn's lemma) and define an inner product by setting
$$\langle v_i,v_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$$
and extending linearly over $V$. Now take the induced norm $\|w\| = \langle w,w\rangle$. However, this structure is not interesting at all, as it basically only depends on the "size" of $V$ (the cardinality of a basis), and not on any other information you have.

Comment: By basis, do you mean Hamel basis?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes, taking a Schauder basis would make impossible extending linearly the inner product defined on the basis vectors.

Comment: In the context of a general vector space, "basis" means a linearly independent spanning set. Which, I guess, is also known as a "Hamel" basis.

Comment: How define this inner product?

Comment: @JarbasDantasSilva Exactly how I said above ($\delta_{ij}$ being $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ else, and extending by linearity).

Comment: But in case infinity? $<x, a_1v_1+a_2v_2+ \cdots +a_n v_n + \cdots > $ if sum not converg?

Comment: @JarbasDantasSilva That's why I specified that we take a *Hamel* basis.